# Issue configuring grunt-filerev-replace

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using Filerev and filerev-replace to create new versions of my CSS and JS files and update the link to the appropriate file version in my HTML document. However I can't seem to get the replace part to work correctly, can someone point me in the right direction.

Current code:

```
filerev: {
  options: {
    encoding: 'utf8',
    algorithm: 'md5',
    length: 8
  },
  source: {
    files: [{
      src: [
        'html/js/iba.min.js',
        'html/css/iba.min.css'
      ]
    }]
  }
},

filerev_replace: {
  options: {
    assets_root: 'tmp/assets/'
  },
  compiled_assets: {
    src: 'html/js/*.{css,js}',
    src: 'html/css/*.{css,js}'
  },
  views: {
    options: {
      views_root: 'tmp/views/'
    },
    src: 'html/templates/default_site/layouts.group/html.html'
  }
},
```

Comment: For one thing, the duplicate `src` properties under `compiled_assets` are not legal JavaScript/JSON.

Comment: Good catch, but that didn't fix the issue. Any other suggestions? There is very little documentation on Github.